# Underscore in dbname giving error

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to connect to a mysql database having the name "_query". 
It gives me the error "No database selected" when I run the following code:

```
mysql_select_db("_query", $con);
$sql = "SELECT * from mdl_sms_msg";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I have spent a lot of time on trying to fix this, please help.

Comment: Did you try changing name of db ?

Comment: add `mysql_select_db("_query", $con) or die(mysql_error())` and let see what happens.

Comment: and also show us how are you trying to connect to the database?

Comment: Please don't write new applications using `mysql_query`. You'll just have to re-write it all later when support for that deprecated method is pulled from PHP.

Comment: Have you opened multiple connections to your database?  You explicitly give the connection `$con` in the call to `mysql_select_db()`, but implicitly use the last opened connection in the call to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Verify that the name of the database is indeed that. If you have access to the console, it would be a good place for you to properly check the name.

Comment: @Shumail92 Yes I have tried changing the db name. It works with any other name but the problem occurs with the db name having _ at the start. zzlalani It gives Unknown database '_query' when placing the die part.